# Symfony 2.1 - Custom Json Annotation Listener

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

For a Symfony 2.1 project, I'm trying to create a new annotation @Json() that will register a listener that will create the JsonResponse object automatically when I return an array. I've got it working, but for some reason the listener is *always* called, even on methods that don't have the @Json annotation. I'm assuming my approach works, since the Sensio extra bundle does this with the @Template annotation.

Here is my annotation code.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Bundle\Annotations;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Json extends \Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ConfigurationAnnotation
{
    public function getAliasName()
    {
        return 'json';
    }
}
```

Here is my listener code.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Bundle\Listener\Response\Json;

class JsonListener
{
    //..

    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $data = $event->getControllerResult();

        if(is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
            if ($request->attributes->get('_json')) {
                $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse($data));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my yaml definition for the listener.

```
json.listener:
            class:      Company\Bundle\Listener\Response\Json
            arguments:  [@service_container]
            tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView }
```

I'm obviously missing something here because its being registered as a kernel.view listener. How do I change this so that it is only called when a @Json() annotation is present on the controller action?

Comment: That seems correct to me, try and find out where the `_json` attribute is being set.

Comment: @igorw Apparently I had it correct all along - I just assumed I was wrong because I was confused that I should handle the annotation in the listener, and not the other way around. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretend to be the definitive answer.

I'm not sure why your are extending [`ConfigurationAnnotation`](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Configuration/ConfigurationAnnotation.php): its constructor accepts an `array`, but you don't need any configuration for your annotation. Instead, implement [`ConfigurationInterface`](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Configuration/ConfigurationInterface.php):

```
namespace Company\Bundle\Annotations;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Json implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getAliasName()
    {
        return 'json';
    }

    public function allowArray()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sensio [`ControllerListener`](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ControllerListener.php) from SensionFrameworkExtraBundle will read your annotation (merging class with methods annotations) and perform this check:

```
if ($configuration instanceof ConfigurationInterface) {
    if ($configuration->allowArray()) {
        $configurations['_'.$configuration->getAliasName()][] = $configuration;
    } else {
        $configurations['_'.$configuration->getAliasName()] = $configuration;
    }
}
```

Setting a request attribute prefixed with `_`. You are correctly checking for `_json`, so it should work. Try dumping `$request->attributes` in your view event listener. Be sure that your `json.listener` service is correctly loaded too (dump them with `php app/console container:debug >> container.txt`).

If it doesn't work, try adding some debug and print statements [here](https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ControllerListener.php#L80) (find `ControllerListener.php` in your vendor folder):

```
var_dump(array_keys($configurations)); // Should contain _json
```

Remember to make a copy of it before edits, otherwise Composer will throw and error when updating dependencies.

Comment: This is what I needed - I didn't properly understand that the annotations were being set as request attributes and that I should check for them in the listeners. +1

Comment: @JarrodNettles what was the problem then?

Comment: The "problem" was that the listener was even being called. I was looking at how annotations should behave incorrectly. Sorry if that doesn't make sense - either way, epiphany.